# _onGenerateRoute throwing null check operator used on a null value

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using Named router class in which i am giving my routes and i gave this router to MaterialApp onGenerateRoute but this causing null exception.

[This is my router class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ut7VB.jpg)

[image: this is my main method]

Comment: could you add your code, instead of add their screenshots?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a function like below somewhere, which is not visible in code

```
static Route<dynamic>? onGenerateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
  ...
}
```

for more please check
https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments#alternatively-extract-the-arguments-using-ongenerateroute

Comment: I tried this solution but it did not work.

Comment: you are using some where '!' operator where you value is null, please check, try to change it to '?'